# How to set managing unit of a project using git?

Tags: git, configuration

I'd like to set git environment for our project, but I don't know which way is better.

The situation is

- A project creates several SW, scripts and others.
- Some SW and others configure a function together. So these are bound to each other.

I tried to set git managing unit(Root repo) and I thought there were whole project unit and one by a SW unit.

In the former case, it's unnecessary to care of functional dependency among SW and others. But, individual version management of them is not easy.

In the latter case, it's pretty easy but it's unable to reflect functional dependency with others

So you guys, which one are you running your project git using? or do you have the better anything else?